# Databind series of values to object in v-for

Tags: mongodb, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm building a little application to input my workout results for some analysis.
I retrieve the data from a mongodb instance, looking as follows (a single exercise. A workout is simply comprised of all exercises with the same date):

`mongodb document excerpt`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d3b0a6250bb03934ddca46"),
    "date" : "2017-10-01",
    "exercise" : "Row",
    "sets" : [ 
        {
            "resistance" : 42.5
        }, 
        {
            "resistance" : 45
        }, 
        {
            "resistance" : 47.5
        }
    ],
    "intensity" : 5
}
```

The frontend code generates a list of workouts (so, dates...) one of which I can click to generate a table based on the values of a workout (so all exercises with that date) and autofills the fields in edit mode with the previous values in case I want to correct them (this is as far as I've gotten - I've limited it to 4 Sets because wrapping all of it in a `v-for` loop just wouldn't work to even generate the columns dynamically)

`component template excerpt`

```
<table class="tbl tbl_border">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Exercise</th>
                        <th>Set 1</th>
                        <th>Set 2</th>
                        <th>Set 3</th>
                        <th>Set 4</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr v-for="(exercise, exercise_index) in exercises">
                        <th>{{exercise.exercise}}</th>
                        <td v-for="(set, set_index) in exercise.sets" class="tbl_set tbl_border">
                            <p v-if= "edit == false">{{set.resistance}}</p>
                            <input v-else type="text" 
                            :placeholder="set.resistance" 
                            v-model="exercises">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button v-if= "edit == false" @click="enableEditMode"> Edit </button>
                <button v-else @click="saveAndExit"> Save </button>
```

The component contains a `computed` property that retrieves the selected exercise (via `vuex` store)

```
exercises:{
            get: function(){
                return store.state.exercises
            },
            set: function(exercises){

            }
        },
```

The question is: I can now edit the entire table (which I want to), but how do I bind ALL the input values into `objects` (one per row, to fit the data model, would make sense) so I can use them in a function later to send an HTTP request?

Update: here's the fiddle, almost works the same way (it just gets all the workouts at the same time because the backend does the filtering by date):
https://jsfiddle.net/9695c73L/
I hope that clears up how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

1.- First you need to use a **local** copy of your data retrived via vuex.
You can find how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41862768/7508154).

2.- Then you can bind the input values to that **local** data.

```
<input v-else type="text" :placeholder="set.resistance" v-model="set.resistance">
```

Here is an example

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    edit: false,
    exercises: [
     {
        "_id" : "59d3b0a6250bb03934ddca47",
        "date" : "2017-11-01",
        "exercise" : "Row",
        "sets" : [ 
            { "resistance" : 42.5 }, 
            {"resistance" : 45}, 
            { "resistance" : 47.5}
        ],
        "intensity" : 5
     }
     ,
      {
        "_id" : "59d3b0a6250bb03934ddca46",
        "date" : "2017-10-01",
        "exercise" : "Row",
        "sets" : [ 
            { "resistance" : 36.7 }, 
            {"resistance" : 40}, 
            { "resistance" : 42.8}
        ],
        "intensity" : 5
     },
    ],
  },
  methods:{
   saveAndExit: function(){
      // All your data is updated in this.exercises
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
      // here you load your data from vuex
      //this.exercise = ...
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 
  <table>
   <tr>
     <th>Exercise</th>
     <th>Set 1</th>
     <th>Set 2</th>
     <th>Set 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="(exercise, exercise_index) in exercises">
    <td>{{exercise.exercise}}</td>
    
    <td v-for="(set, set_index) in exercise.sets" class="tbl_set tbl_border">
      
      <p v-if="edit == false">{{set.resistance}}</p>
      <input v-else type="text" 
             :placeholder="set.resistance" 
             v-model="set.resistance">
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>

<button v-if="edit == false" @click="edit = true"> Edit </button> 
<button v-else @click="saveAndExit(), edit = false"> Save </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I've been trying back and forth and can't get it to work, I put in a fiddle to maybe clarify how it's supposed to work.