# Default select option to first index when populating via array from Vuex store in Vue Component

Tags: vue.js, select, vuex

I have an array in my Vuex store called Projects. I want to loop through these projects and default to the first item. I have setup a v-model on this select input so I can use the chosen result in my local component.

[I read on this SO how I can use v-modal to do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668363/select-always-first-value-select-vue-js/39668869?noredirect=1#comment99881065_39668869)

However because I populate via Vuex store I think I need to do differently.

So I made my Vuex action I call a promise so in my component I can determine when it has resolved, so I can then populate my local component data (and thus the select input).

```
loadData: ({ commit }, payload) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // get projects on load
    axios
      .get("/api/projects/")
      .then(function(response) {
        commit("updateProjects", response.data);
        resolve();
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
        throw error;
      });
  });
};
```

Then in my local component I have the following triggered on created():

```
created() {
  this.$store
    .dispatch("loadData")
    .then((this.modalCreate.project = this.projects)); // dispatch loading
}
```

And within my component I have the following:

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="modalCreate.project">
  <option
    v-for="(project, index) in projects"
    :value="project"
    :key="project.id"
  >
    {{ project.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

In the above I have used `mapState` to map my `store.projects` to local projects.

In this setup I can see the select options populated from the local projects (from Vuex) but I cannot get the select form to default to the first index.

I suspect this is because I have not correctly made my `modalCreate.project` the first `store.project` object. Currently my `modalCreate.project` is undefined.

Most grateful for any advice on how to best achieve this and whether mapping Vuex state to local state is over-engineering a solution.

--

Perhaps this cloning solution can be applied? I had no luck though: [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41862768/2468603)

Comment: Your `<option />` should have a `selected` attribute on the first index. E.g. `<option :selected={ somethingSelectedHere || index === 0 }/>`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to select the first project (index === 0) as your default project:

```
created() {
  this.$store
    .dispatch("loadData")
    .then(() => {
        this.modelCreate = {
            ...this.modelCreate,
            project: this.projects[0]
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this.modalCreate.project not populating, but I can console.log(this.projects[0]); and see that the correct project object is being returned.... Feel like we're nearly there...